# Including published Matlab code and figures in separate LaTeX document

Tags: include, matlab

I'm writing up a homework set in LaTeX.  I'm writing the theoretical parts of the homework using LaTeX, and the implementation in Matlab.  I want to combine these two easily.  My problem is:

How do you include the Matlab published `.tex` file in a separate LaTeX document?

I know LaTeX has packages which can import formatted Matlab code into a LaTeX document.  You can also import Matlab-generated `.eps` figures.  What I want to do is include the Matlab published `.tex` file (which includes the code and figures placed appropriately) using `\include{publishedMfile.tex}` in the middle of my LaTeX document.  However, the published `.tex` file is designed to be standalone, so it has a preamble, which prevents me from including it.

Here's a sample Matlab published file:
[file.tex](http://www.stanford.edu/~ruslank/hw1_prob1.tex)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It would be helpful it you provide a sample .tex file produced by Matlab? I think what you want can be done with the `standalone` package, but would be good to be able to test it.

Comment: You might want to use the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what the Matlib .tex file looks like, but from your description it is a complete .tex file that can be compiled by itself.  If that is the case, you should be able to use [the `standalone` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone) to input that file into your LaTeX document as such. So, assuming that the file is called **publishedMfile.tex**, then your main file would just input it as such:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
Here is the graph of an ellipse:

\input{publishedMfile}
\end{document}
```

For this test, I used the following as the **publishedMfile** (which is obviously not from Matlib) file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (EllipseOrigin) at (0,0);
\newcommand*{\XRadius}{4.0}
\newcommand*{\YRadius}{3.0}

\draw [blue, thin, ->] (-5,0) -- (5,0) node [right] {$x$};
\draw [blue, thin, ->] (0,-4) -- (0,4) node [above] {$y$};

\draw [red, ultra thick]% Graph Ellipse
    (EllipseOrigin) ellipse [x radius=\XRadius,y radius=\YRadius];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like the standalone package works well for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply copy the required packages and commands such as `\usepackage{...}` and `\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.5}` or `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` etc. and put it into your documents preamble. After that there is no reason to not to include it in your document. Otherwise please elaborate your question further to narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: My goal is to use the autogenerated Matlab tex file and include it in my custom document.  If I have to cut out the autogenerated preamble every time I change my Matlab code that would get tedious.